# Do we know Al Bundy's age in the show?

Tags: character, married-with-children

Do we know Al Bundy's age in the show? I tried googling but to no avail.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to a [wiki about the show](https://marriedwithchildren.fandom.com/wiki/Polk_High_School) he was "Class of 1966" (wikipedia mentions him scoring 4 touchdowns in one football game in 1966) which would mean he was born c. 1948, so the first season he would be approximately 39.

They also celebrated their 16th wedding anniversary in the first season, which puts him at around 23 for the wedding, which was bog-standard marriage age in my neighborhood c. 1970.

This is complicated a little because he claims at one point (S11E12) to have signed his dad up for the Korean War, which was 1950-1953.

Comment: The naughty seven year old might have signed his dad up for the Korean War (atleast in the Married With Children universe).

Comment: I mean, technically the Korean War never officially ended, so maybe he signed him up later than that, as a joke...

Comment: If he was class of 66, wouldn't his last football season have ended in December, 65?

Comment: @Barmar Most likely, but it doesn't really affect the answer because of the range of dates he could have been born and still graduated in '66.

Comment: True, it's just another way in which the show seems to be inconsistent about the details of his life. I suspect this was not something the creators obsessed about.

Comment: _"wikipedia mentions him scoring 4 touchdowns"_, he also mentions that himself… repeatedly.

Comment: @ouflak There's also the (let's be honest, not unlikely) possibility that Al failed a grade or two and was older than that

Comment: @Barmar It was the 1966 Championship game.  The year used in titles like that typically refers to the graduation year, even if the game itself was played in the fall of 1965

Comment: @Kevin Not in Washington: https://www.maxpreps.com/playoffs/brackets.aspx?gendersport=boys,football&state=wa

Comment: While I didn't put it in front of the (derived) age, I used "c. 1948" which means "circa" which means uncertain. In my line of work, a circa date (year) is usually assumed to to be +/- 2 but probably not +/- 5.